# remove string after a white space php

Tags: php, regex

I am a beginner, in php, and i want to use regex to remove a string after the first white space i found.
My code is like:

```
<?php

   $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
   $adress = "https://...";
   $timeout = 40;
   $ch = curl_init($adress);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

    if (strpos($adress, 'https://') === 0) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    $page_content = curl_exec($ch); 
    $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $node = $dom->loadHTML($page_content);
    $listeImages = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($listeImages as $image)
    {
        $link = $dom->createElement("a");
        $href = $dom->createAttribute('srcset');
        $href->value = $image->getAttribute('srcset');
        $value_img = print( $href -> nodeValue.'<br />');
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $image);
        $link->appendChild($href);

        /*$exclusion_space_url=array(' ', ' 1x');
        $url_cleaned=$this->$value_img;
        foreach ($exclusion_space_url as $key=>$value) {
        $url_cleaned=str_replace($value," ",$url_cleaned);*/ ***what i tried to do***
        }     
    }

   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And the result of this is :

An html page with 3-4 lines of url serparate with space

Thank for your help

Comment: `$split = preg_split("/\s/", $input_line);` and then `$split[0]` is what you need.

Comment: Ther is a lot of code unrelated to you question. Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
yes i know but i tried to be as explicit as i can that's why !!

Comment: You can use either preg_match to get the first part or preg_replace to get rid of the last part. Like:  preg_replace('/\s+.*/','',$yourUrl);

Comment: @apokryfos what you did is the same as using explode(' ',$string);

Comment: Thank  to all of you i'll try your answers and let you know

Comment: @M.I. OP asked for regex. Besides, `\s` captures `\t` as well (possibly some others).

Comment: @all please anyone know how to recover $href -> nodeValue.  in a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourString = "Your String With Space";
$str= strtok($yourString,' ');
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sufiyan Malek , but the problem is  $yourString in your case refer to a particular  string .  In my case, i 'll use foreach barcode a different result .
For example if i got : case1 $barcode = 215697 and case2 $barecode2 = 4569875, i'll get a different result  in my html result

Excuse my english ^^